# Share a link via URL scheme to Telegram

Tags: html, web, url-scheme

I want to share a link via URL scheme for Telegram.

I have created this:

```
tg://msg?text = www.example.com?t=12
```

The link, opens telegram but nothing else happens.

I have used the same code for Viber, and it works:

```
viber://forward?text = www.example.com?t=12
```

And it opens a new message in Viber with this text:

> www.example.com

In the other words, it cuts my URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 76):

You can also use telegram.me share link which falls back to webogram if a telegram app is not installed on the device.

`https://telegram.me/share/url?url=<URL>&text=<TEXT>`

Comment: can we open telegram to start chat with bot selected (not a number) i.e something like this tg://msg?text=HI there&to=@my_bot

Comment: @Qadir Hussain have you found any solution yet? 
contact added in phone contact, i use tg://msg?text=hi&to=+91XX then ios redirect to user chat screen, how cant i do in android?

Comment: @Maulikpatel this should help for android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627167/how-to-send-a-intent-with-telegram

Comment: @QadirHussain it will redirect me to telegram but not particular user chat screen.

Comment: @Maulikpatel don't know about this in android

Answer (score 18):

This works with me:

```
tg://msg?text=Mi_mensaje&to=+1555999
```

Comment: How to check isTelegram installed? in swift

Comment: can we open telegram to start chat with bot selected (not a number) i.e something like this
tg://msg?text=Mi_mensaje&to=@my_bot

Comment: @QadirHussain to open telegram to start chat with bot use url like 'https://telegram.me/my_bot' . it redirects you to chat screen with that bot.

Comment: <a href = "tg://msg?text=Mi_mensaje&to=+1555999"><telegram</a> this is opening 'xdg' and after we should select contact. Is there any solution to open xdg and then contact and having sending message. thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the userId ( not a username ) like 854845663
How can I use it instead of a username?

Answer (score 16):

You have the following options for a URL...

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
tg://msg_url?url={url}&text={text}
```

In case you want to confirm, here is the official API source: [Core.Telegram.org: Widgets -> Sharing Button](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons).

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#telegramme

[image: Social Share URLs]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the link `telegram.me` which will provide a preview page with an alert requesting to open the link in the application.

```
https://telegram.me/share/url?url=<URL>&text=<TEXT>
```

[image]

The second option is calling the application link directly:

```
tg://msg_url?url=<url>&text=<encoded-text>
```

> I particularly prefer the second option, which also works on desktop applications.

Answer (score 5):

For Telegram share:

Objective C:

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tg://msg?text=test"]){
 [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tg://msg?text=test"]
}else{
 //App not installed.
}
```

Swift 3.0:

```
let urlString = "tg://msg?text=test"
let tgUrl = URL.init(string:urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(tgUrl!)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(tgUrl!)
    }else
    {
       //App not installed.
    }
```

If you have used canOpenURL, then need to add in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>tg</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href = "https://telegram.me/share/url?url=<URL>&text=<TEXT>">Telegram</a>
```

with this we can open xdg of telegram and if we select contact , by default sending text will come in message field.

Answer (score 3):

PHP

```
<a href="tg://msg?text=<?php echo rawurlencode($gotoURL); ?>">Link</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>TEXT="any text or url";</script>

<a onclick="window.location='tg://msg?text='+encodeURIComponent(TEXT);">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use localhost therefore it does not show share. try it in live host

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using the protocol for the desktop applications because it does not work on the evolving web: it does not work on Web apps, ChromeOS, or some mobile devices.

Always use the NEW way: https://t.me because it will open the Telegram DESKTOP app in Windows\Linux\Mac IF THE USER WANTS\HAS it, otherwise it will open the WEB page\web app which is THE WAY.

1. https://web.telegram.org/k
2. https://web.telegram.org/z

Telegram has TWO web apps that have been building out for the past year!

Both are great, adding TONs of parity, and have different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the Telegram is installed you can do the following (borrowed from the Whatsapp sharer module of ShareKit):

```
BOOL isTelegramInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tg://msg?text=test"]];
```

iOS checks if there's any app installed which can handle the tg:// scheme, which is Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested, this way it works both opening telegram app or browser in case it's not installed:

```
let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://t.me/<YOUR ID>")!
UIApplication.shared.open(webURL as URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have **two problems**:

1. On one hand you are using the wrong scheme for sharing URLs, the correct one is *msg_url*;
2. On the other hand you are trying to share a URL with parameters. You need to encode your ? in order to make it work. The percent code is %3F
3. Extra Tip: Also if you want it to be a link once shared you should include the HTTPS:// encoded of course.

Try this and you'll see it works fine: tg://msg_url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3Ft=12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open chat with bot or people, just write this simple code

```
<a href="https://t.me/targetedusername">
```