# redirect android app to telegram messenger

Tags: android, redirect

I want to code redirection from my app to telegram. I didnt find any examples of it, so I tried to do it by the same way like I did with WhatsApp redirection, **it didn't work**, could you give me some advise? Below my code of WhatsApp redirection, it works, I tried the same by replacing strings "whatsapp" with "telegram", result is it goes to catch() when it checks the existance of package:

```
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: did you try this `org.telegram.messenger`

Comment: @Logic,  it works! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21627262/4144914 it will solve your Problem